# Wordpress set title?

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website which I've added a couple of custom pages to. Everything works fine except that those custom pages don't have titles. Is there a (short?) way to add titles to those custom pages?

Edit: I think I was unclear, I meant the title at the top of the browser (html title) not the title of a wordpress page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can go to the 'Pages' page where it lists the pages and use quick edit:

[image: Pages]

Hover over a page and click 'Quick Edit'

[image: Quick Edit]

Make your changes, and then click 'Update'.

EDIT

I seem to have misunderstood the question. Yes, WordPress gives you a filter to play with the title. See below:

```
function my_title_tag_filterer( $title, $separator, $separator_location ){
  //You can do things to the title here.
  return $title;
}

add_filter( 'wp_filter', 'my_title_tag_filterer' );
```

`$title` is the title, `$separator` is the text that goes between the blog title and the page title, and `$separator_location` is where the separator goes in relation to the page title.

Comment: I didn't mean that with 'custom page'. I meant one which is not editable in the back-end. One I coded.. :P

Comment: Is there no way to set the title in code (without screwing up the title for the non-custom pages)